# trying to get id's from array of objects and push those id's into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get the id's from array of objects using the below code

```
const opaqueMaterialSecondaryIds = Object.values(library?.layers).reduce((acc, opaque) => {
    acc.push(...opaque.map(e => e.id));
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

and getting an error at `opaque.map` is not function and the object is looks like as below

[image]

i am not sure where i am doing wrong with the above code. Could any one please suggest any ideas on this, many thanks in advance.

Comment: can you post your json here

Comment: `library?.layers?.map(item => item.id)`

Comment: Why use reduce on layers rather than map? - It appears opaque is an object - hence, no map method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an Array method and doesn't exist in an object.

Each item in your `library?.layers` is an object, so `opaque.map` is not a function.

Side note 1: `library?.layers` is already an object, so you don't need to call `Object.values()` but can instead directly use `library?.layers?.reduce()`.

Side note 2: if your purpose is to get the ids of all `opaque` objects, you can just do:

```
const opaqueMaterialSecondaryIds = library?.layers?.map(opaque => opaque.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your structure is what it looks like:

```
const layers = [
  {
    # other attributes,
    id: 'id-1',
    # other attributes,
  },
  {
    ...
  },
];
```

I think all you need is this:

```
const layerIds = layers.map((l) => l.id);
console.log(layerIds);
# Output: ['id-1', 'id-2']
```